# Destruction of records in around_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Before updating the record, I need to do some checks. As a result of one of the checks, I need to destroy the record that is being updated.

I have two questions.

1. How good is this solution? (*I need to delete a record on update because a similar record was found among the old ones*)
2. What is the correct way to implement cancellation of an update after a record has been destroyed?

I wrote this simple code:

```rb
return yield unless title_changed?

tmp_destroyed = false

# some code

tmp_destroyed = true if destroy!

# some code

return if tmp_destroyed

yield
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right decision.

Can you please tell me if I'm doing everything right? And did I choose the right way for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, before updating the record, check your conditions in controller and if your conditions is true then delete the record instead of checking in model callback methods.